# How much longer does it take to paint a similar box with $5$ times more volume?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, unit-of-measure

This is a question from a precalculus class that I'm a TA for.

> You build a box that has a volume of 100 cubic feet. It takes two people ten minutes to spray paint this box. How many minutes does it take three people to spray paint a similar box that has a volume of 500 cubic feet? Assume that the area of surface to be covered is proportionate to both the number of people working and the time spent spray painting.

A student just asked me how to answer it, so I figured I'd write up the correct calculations and post it online to help anyone else who may wander across it.

Comment: Does the box have any flaps?

Comment: I'd assume no flaps or anything. It's just a precal questions, so let's keep it simple. Besides, it shouldn't matter so long as the two boxes are similar.

Comment: Wrong assumptions can have horrible consequences. Where I come from, boxes have two sets of flaps, and the inner flaps often do not cover the entire top of the box. Assuming you'd like those painted too, the area may not scale linearly with $k^2$.

Comment: Mike, I have to ask: why don't you use website for the course you are teaching to post problems and solutions for your students?

Comment: @Ennar The official course website is on a system by Blackboard, which doesn't support mathematics typesetting, and is rather unreliable. Additionally if they were hosted there, the solutions would have to be copied/reuploaded each quarter the class is taught. I could host them on my personal website, but then I'd have to make a course webpage, etc, and that's a bunch of work. But really, why wouldn't I just post them here?

Comment: I have nothing against it, it just seems odd to communicate with your students this way.

Comment: @LinAlg As long as the linear dimensions of the flaps scale by $k$ too, regardless of whether the inner flaps cover the entire opening of the box, I think the entire surface area will still scale by $k^2$. But that is a big assumption that needs to be made about the situation in the problem, since it only says how the *volume* of the boxes are changing.

Comment: I find it peculiar that there is no mention of the shape of the two boxes. Perhaps that is the whole point of the exercise: if you don't know the shape, you can not conclude anything about the relation between volume and surface area.

Comment: @M.Wind I've added the word [*similar*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Similarity_(geometry)) to the statement of the question to hopefully alleviate your, and anyone else's, concerns about the question being well-posed.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Suppose that the linear measurements of the large box are $k$ times the linear measurements of the small box. This would mean $3$-dimensional measurements, like volume, of the large box will be $k^3$ times those of the small box. So $100k^3 = 500$, and we see that $k = \sqrt[3]{5}$. The amount of surface area of a box to be spray painted is a $2$-dimensional measurement, so it will scale by $k^2 = \sqrt[3]{25}$. Since there is this much more surface area to spray paint, it will take this much more time to paint it, and so it'll take two people $10\sqrt[3]{5}$ minutes to paint the larger box. Dividing the work among three people instead of two, we see that to paint the large box it'll take 
$$
\frac{2}{3}10\sqrt[3]{25} \text{ minutes.}
$$

Answer (score 3):

For similar rectangular boxes, area ratio is the square of length ratio and volume ratio the cube of length ratio. So $5$ times the volume is $5^{\frac{2}{3}}$ times the area which is equivalent to $5^{\frac{2}{3}}$ boxes.

If it takes two people $10$ minutes to spray paint a box then the rate is $20$ minutes per person per box

For three people, it will take $\frac{20}{3} \cdot 5^{\frac{2}{3}}$ minutes to paint the $500$ cubic foot box.

$T = 19.4934$ minutes or $19$ min $29.6$ sec.

Answer (score 3):

Refer to the table:
$$\begin{array}{c|c|c|c}
\text{People} & \text{Time} & \text{Surface}\\
\hline
\color{blue}2 & \color{blue}{10} & \color{blue}{6\sqrt[3]{100^2}}&\text{divide by $2$}\\
\color{blue}1 & \color{blue}{10} & \color{blue}{3\sqrt[3]{100^2}}&\text{multuply by $3$}\\
\color{blue}3 & \color{blue}{10} & \color{blue}{9\sqrt[3]{100^2}}\\
\hline
\color{red}3 &  \color{red}x & \color{red}{6\sqrt[3]{500^2}}\\
\end{array} \Rightarrow \color{red}x=\frac{\color{red}{6\sqrt[3]{500^2}}\cdot \color{blue}{10}}{\color{blue}{9\sqrt[3]{100^2}}}=\frac{20\sqrt[3]{25}}{3}.$$